# You're going to like it

Tags: pronombres, conjugación

In my spanish course I was presented with:

```
te va a encantar
```

As a translation of `You're going to like it`.  But what confuses me is the combination of the pronoun `te` with the verb conjugation`va`.

Why isn't the translation:

```
te vas a encantar
```

Comment: To me "te va a encantar" is closer to "you are going to **love** it" that to "you are going to like it". The latter one is just "te va a gustar/ te gustará".

Comment: @Diego .. probably my fault with the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for the same reason that it's "te encanta" and not "te encantas". (remember, *gustar* and *encantar* don't mean to like/love, they mean *to please* and *to enchant*, that is, causing enjoyment *to/for* someone)

```
te      encanta
you.IO  enchant.PRES.3RD.SING
"It enchants you"

te      va a encantar
you.IO  enchant.FUT.3RD.SING
"It is going to enchant you"
```

There's nothing grammatically wrong *per se* with *te vas a encatar*, but then you get:

```
te      vas a encantar
you.RO  enchant.FUT.2ND.SING
"You are going to enchant yourself"
```

Which is a very different sentence, effectively meaning *you are going to love (non-amorously) yourself*

Comment: Thank you .. I was mistaken with who was doing the liking.

Answer (score 0):

Your correction is right (in literal way).

But the expression "va a" is an auxiliary verb (**ir a**) marking the future tense. Then

> te va a encantar
>
> vas a llegar tarde

means

> te encantará
>
> llegarás tarde

and that is also correct.